# Installing python packages for web application on Azure

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure and I am facing difficulty in installing python packages on my Azure platform. I followed the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python and successfully deployed it. But for installing custom packages I am facing issues. Please help me out.
I also tried installing via pip on bash from application

Comment: what is your issue ?

Comment: I was trying to install some packages by going to the bash of web application and doing a pip install. Never mind I figured it out by including requirements.txt

Comment: @yatishhr, please help post your answer and mark it as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as adding requirements.txt. Add your packages one after another in a line  like -

```
beautifulsoup
numpy
pandas
```

You can also mention version numbers for individual packages